# How to display decoded unicode character values in input type text?

Tags: html, unicode, input

I am encoding in the DB some characters `(", \)` with their unicode values `(&#34; , &#92;)`. When I display those fields in HTML they are displayed fine, but when I put the in 
`<input type="text">` elements I get the information displayed with the actual value from the DB `(&#34; , &#92;)` instead of their decoded value `(", \)`.

How do I display the decoded value of Unicode characters in input type text elements?

Comment: 1) That's only "Unicode characters" in the sense that they have a Unicode code point, like any other character out there. 2) Why are you encoding them to HTML entities in your DB? 3) Show your output code or at least the final HTML.

Comment: I am feeding the fields to a jquery library that treats this output as a Json. These characters break the JSON object that it is expecting, so I would have to get them already escaped. My problem is that the same fields are feeded to the library that expects a JSON object and to some of the input fields.

Comment: Then don't needlessly HTML-entity encode them in your database, or decode them again when needed.

Comment: I'm open to a suggestion on how to feed a valid JSON object from fields containing characters that break it, to a library that I don't have access to modify.

Comment: Reading the code of the library, it does an ajax call to my controller and treats the response as a JSON (if this is of any help).

Comment: If you're sending the value "&#34;", then you'll get the value "&#34;" displayed. If you need """, send """.

Comment: html entities don't display properly in text areas. You would be better serving your whole page as unicode and sending the raw characters.

Comment: I know that I'm sending "$#34" to the input texts, and I'm sending the same value to plain HTML code. HTML interprets that code and it displays the characters correctly, while the input type texts don't. The problem is that I need to display the information from a given field in 2 places, plain HTML (as text) and input type text elements. deceze I would appreciate if you would stop trolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was a Spring option (attribute `htmlEscape`) that escaped HTML content server side on the input fields.

When I set that attribute on the input fields to false, the sequence `&#34` wasn't escaped anymore and the character on the response received by the client was instead `"`.

Unfortunately I didn't specify in the question that the input type tag on the JSP was a Spring specific, instead of the HTML one, because I didn't think that is a key factor in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I am feeding the fields to a jquery library that treats this output as a Json.

Then I guess that when populating inputs you are using `val()` which takes text as input and when populating other parts of the page you are using `html()`, which takes HTML as input.

Don't send JSON containing HTML. Send JSON containing text. Convert to HTML when you need HTML. Don't store HTML in the database.

> These characters break the JSON object that it is expecting, so I would have to get them already escaped.

You should encode them as JSON, not as HTML. You shouldn't have this problem unless you are trying to generate JSON by mashing together strings. Don't do that, use a JSON library instead.

Comment: The library I'm talking about is jQGrid. We're feeding a .jsp file that consists of a JSON object. We used this approach in order to easily write HTML inside the Table the library creates, but unfortunately it comes with the drawback of the user inserting the unwanted characters. It is too late to change to an approach of feeding a JSON object and to encode the response as "appliaction/json" as there are a considerable number of places that would need modifications.